# How to persist with inverse @OneToOne mapping involving @JoinFormula?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to map the relation between the following tables in Hibernate:

```
create table binary (
    id number not null primary key,
    data blob,
    entity_class varchar(255) not null,
    entity_id number not null,
    unique (entity_id, entity_class)
);

create table container_entity (
    id number not null primary key,
    ...
);
```

The binary table is supposed to hold binary data for arbitrary other tables, the "foreign key" - though not in database terms - is composed of `binary.entity_class` and `binary.entity_id`. This is a construct that I have to accept for now and it seems to be causing confusion here. The column `binary.entity_id` references the primary key of the aggregated table, while `binary.entity_class` defines the aggregated table itself:

```
BINARY                               CONTAINER_ENTITY_A  CONTAINER_ENTITY_B 
id  entity_class      entity_id      id                  id                    ...
-------------------------------      ------------------  ------------------
1   ContainerEntityA  1          ->  1                                         ...
2   ContainerEntityB  1          ->                      1
3   ContainerEntityB  2          ->                      2
```

The mapping in ContainerEntity is already working find when used read-only:

```
@Entity @Table(name="container_entity_a")
public class ContainerEntityA {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({ 
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = 
      @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "entity_id", 
        insertable=false, updatable=false)),
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = 
      @JoinFormula(value = "'ContainerEntityA'", referencedColumnName = "entity_class")) 
  })
  private Binary binary;

  public void setBinary(Binary aBinary) {
    aBinary.setEntityClass("ContainerEntityA");
    this.binary = aBinary;
  }
}

@Entity @Table(name="binary")
public class Binary {
  @Column(name = "entity_id", nullable = false)
  private Long entityId;

  @Column(name = "entity_class", nullable = false)
  private String entityClass;
}
```

But I am having problems persisting ContainerEntity:

- If I just specify `CascadeType.PERSIST` Hibernate fails to set `binary.entity_id`.
- If I do not cascade-persist, I don't know when to set `binary.entity_id` myself, how to persist the mapped object, and I end up with:

  org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ContainerEntity.binary -> Binary

In other words, I would like but currently fail to persist both entities like this:

```
containerEntity = new ContainerEntity();
containerEntity.setBinary( new Binary() );
entityManager.persist(containerEntity);
```

Any ideas or helpful suggestions?

---

**Note on the bounty:** There is no answer to this question yet that I can accept as 'correct', although there is one more hint that I'll check on next week. The time for my bounty is over though, so I'll award it to the answer coming closest so far.

Comment: What's with the `$` and `->` in your last code snippet? Are you writing in Perl for some reason?

Comment: @TomAnderson More like lack of sleep and concentration. Thanks for the heads up, I fixed that!

Comment: Have you checked my Idea3?

Comment: From the information you gave I believe my updated solution does *exactly* what you want (cascading save, load and with zero database changes aother than table or sequence for ID allocation). I simply cannot see any other way of getting this to work. Performance may not be great due to the Union queries required with Table per class but then your database is not great so you'd have to live with that.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I've caught the flu, so it might be a couple more days until I can evaluate your solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, please try the following which I think works perfectly. I have tested and can load and save the Container and associated entities as expected.

Firstly Containers will have to extend from some common Entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Container {

    //cannot use identity here however a table or sequence should work so long as
    //the initial value is > current max ids from all container tables.
    @Id
    @TableGenerator(initialValue = 10000, allocationSize = 100, table = "id_gen", name = "id_gen")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "id_gen")
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public BinaryData getBinaryData() {
        return getData().size() > 0 ? getData().get(0) : null;
    }

    public void setBinaryData(BinaryData binaryData) {
        binaryData.setContainerClass(getName());
        binaryData.setContainer(this);

        this.getData().clear();
        this.getData().add(binaryData);
    }

    protected abstract List<BinaryData> getData();

    protected abstract String getName();
}
```

Concrete ContainerA. The relationship has to be mapped as a OneToMany however an additional @Where clause (and your database unique key) effectively makes this a @OneToOne. Clients of this class can see it as a single ended association:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "container_a")
public class ContainerA extends Container {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "container", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Where(clause = "container_class = 'container_a'")
    private List<BinaryData> binaryData;

    public ContainerA() {
        binaryData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<BinaryData> getData() {
        return binaryData;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
        return "container_a";
    }
}
```

ContainerB

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "container_b")
public class ContainerB extends Container {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "container", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Where(clause = "container_class = 'container_b'")
    private List<BinaryData> binaryData;

    public ContainerB() {
        binaryData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<BinaryData> getData() {
        return binaryData;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
        return "container_b";
    }
}
```

The mapping back form BinaryData to Container requires use of Hibernate's @Any mapping.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "binary_data")
public class BinaryData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "container_class"))
    @AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string", metaValues = {
            @MetaValue(targetEntity = ContainerA.class, value = "container_a"),
            @MetaValue(targetEntity = ContainerB.class, value = "container_b") })
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")
    private Container container;

    @Column(name = "container_class")
    private String containerClass;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Container getContainer() {
        return container;
    }

    public void setContainer(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public String getContainerClass() {
        return containerClass;
    }

    public void setContainerClass(String containerClass) {
        this.containerClass = containerClass;
    }
}
```

The following tests passed as expected:

```
public class ContainerDaoTest extends BaseDaoTest {

    @Test
    public void testSaveEntityA() {

        ContainerA c = new ContainerA();

        BinaryData b = new BinaryData();
        c.setBinaryData(b);

        ContainerDao dao = new ContainerDao();
        dao.persist(c);

        c = dao.load(c.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(c.getId(), b.getContainer().getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoadEntity() {
        ContainerA c = new ContainerDao().load(2l);
        Assert.assertEquals(new Long(3), c.getBinaryData().getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(new Long(2), c.getBinaryData().getContainer().getId());
        Assert.assertEquals("container_a", c.getBinaryData().getContainerClass());
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getDataSetPaths() {
        return new String[] { "/stack/container.xml", "/stack/binarydata.xml" };
    }
}
```

When using the following datasets:

```
<dataset>
    <container_a id="1" />
    <container_a id="2" />
    <container_b id="1" />
    <container_b id="2" />
</dataset>

<dataset>
    <binary_data id="1" container_class="container_a" entity_id="1" />
    <binary_data id="2" container_class="container_b" entity_id="2" />
    <binary_data id="3" container_class="container_a" entity_id="2" />
    <binary_data id="4" container_class="container_b" entity_id="1" />
</dataset>
```

Comment: This is not quite the elegant solution I had hoped for. But it does meet the requirements and it is probably as close as we will get. I'Ve implemented and tested this in our context and can confirm that it works. The two minor drawbacks of this solution: 1) The OneToMay 'hack' and 2) the fact that the BinaryData class has to be updated for each new container. But anyway: Thank you very much for your effort and input!

Comment: Yes, not the most elegant but, given the DB schema, a pretty clever solution. Hopefully the rest of your database is a bit more straightforward to work with!

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem is that Hibernate is an object-relational mapper, and this database is not really relational. Specifically, the use of values in a column to refer to table names falls outside the relational model. Ideally, you would fix this by changing the schema, but it sounds like that is not possible.

Are you wedded to autogenerating the IDs? If not, you could generate IDs for container entities in your application code before persisting then, and copy these into their `Binary` objects when they are attached.

If you need to autogenerate, something you might try would be to cascade the persist, and to use a [`@PostPersist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PostPersist.html) lifecycle callback method on `ContainerEntityA` to copy the generated ID into the `Binary`. Like this:

```
@Entity
public class ContainerEntityA {
    @PostPersist
    public void copyIdToBinary() {
        binary.setEntityId(id);
    }
}
```

You can be sure that this method will see the generated value for the ID; the [spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html) states (in section 3.5, 'Entity Listeners and Callback Methods') that:

> Generated primary key values are available in the PostPersist method.

However, what you can't be sure of is that the update to the `Binary`'s `entityId` field will happen before it is persisted. The spec warns that:

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not [...] access other entity instances

And:

> It is implementation-dependent as to whether callback methods are invoked before or after the cascading of the lifecycle events to related entities. Applications should not depend on this ordering.

So, this is not a great solution. It's not portable, and it might not work. But it's possible that it will work with your particular version of Hibernate, and if it does, it may be the cleanest solution that you can use without changing the schema.

Comment: Hey, that is my Idea3 :) (see the comments also for the fact that the id is available in the @PostPersist method). Besides, why is that not portable and it might not work?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you switch the join column name and the referenceColumnName ?
Like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false))
```

Comment: No, I'm sure that the JoinColumn is correct. After all, Hibernate is correctly reading and populating the binary property of ContainerEntity when accessing an existing one.

Comment: Can you edit an include code with all mappings for both classes and the code creating and persisting a new entity?

Comment: @AlanHay I always try to be as concise as possible. But you are right, I might have left out too much here, so I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

<del>**Idea1 (does not work)**:
Have you tried to remove `insertable=false` (i.e shouldn't `insertable` be true?) from the `@JoinColumn` and adding mappingBy="entityId" in the @OneToOne annotation?</del>

**Idea2**: (you might change the order the entities are saved).

1.remove the cascading

2.

```
containerEntity = new ContainerEntity();
entityManager.persist(containerEntity);
binary = new Binary();
containerEntity.set( binary );
entityManager.persist(binary);
entityManager.merge(containerEntity);

....  in ContainerEntity
public void setBinary(Binary aBinary) {
  aBinary.setEntityClass("ContainerEntity");
  aBinary.setEntityId(this.id);
  this.binary = aBinary;
}
```

**Idea3:**
Specify CascadeType.PERSIST & set binary.entityId to 0 for example. With a `@PostPersist` on `EntityContainer` set the `entityId` of its binary to the correct value. This will leave inconsistent your DB for a short moment, but if you do that in a transaction, it is not a problem.

Comment: The upper half of your code will persist both entities. This is basically (along with variants) the only way I've found and it is not very convenient. Also, it will throw an exception if `$containerEntity->set( $binary )` is called before before `$entityManager.persist($containerEntity)`.

Comment: I have also tried "Idea1", but this causes Hibernate to complaing at startup: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: ContainerEntity column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Comment: Idea2: yes, it is not very convenient, but it is a working suggestion. Indeed, it would throw an exception, if the order of those calls would not be the one specified by you, but my code respects it, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you correctly. I tried and added a `@JoinColumn` outside the `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas`. Hibernate seems to ignore the latter which then breaks reading the Binary entity.

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. That was a bad idea (I misinterpreted the exception message). I corrected Idea1. Could you try it?

Comment: I suppose you mean adding `mappedBy = "entityId"`? That won't work because there is no mapping in Binary for obvious reasons: `Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: Binary.entityId in mappedBy of ContainerEntityA.binary`

Comment: Yes, Idea1 if to be implemented, needs some bigger modifications, like introducing another `BinaryA` class. But what do you think about Idea3 :)

Comment: Idea3 won't work, I'm afraid. When EntityContainer is persisted it is also flushed and loaded anew from the database. Hibernate will fail to load the aggregated Binary entity because it references the wrong entity_id. So I cannot set in in AfterPersist. Also, write operations are not allowed in AfterPersist methods iirc.

Comment: About Idea3: why would Hibernate load the `EntityContainer` after persist? It may do that, but you can be sure, that the instance you have in code is not touched/replaced. Also I guarantee that you are allowed to change persistent data in `@PostPersist` methods (also it is guaranteed that all IDs are already available then). Please simply try, as it is very easy and let me know.

Comment: I did not get around to trying your last idea as I implemented Alan Hay's solution. Also, I share Tom Anderson concerns about using @PostPersist that he backed with quotes from the documentation. In any case, thanks again for your time and support!